# rqt_graph not working despite having the package

Tags: ros, rqt

As the title mentioned, I'm trying to use rqt_graph to observe my nodes. However, it showed

> ```
> rvl224@eervl224:~/brian2lee/gazebo/forklift_test$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
> [rospack] Error: package 'rqt_graph' not found
> rvl224@eervl224:~/brian2lee/gazebo/forklift_test$ rqt_graph
> rqt_graph：無此指令
> ```

(The chinese part is rqt_graph: command not found) But there literally rqt-gui 0.5.3 & rqt-gui-py
0.5.3 in my pip list. Have no idea how to solve it. Just in case it's problem like package conflict here's the pip list.

```
Package                              Version             
------------------------------------ --------------------
actionlib                            1.14.0              
aiosignal                            1.2.0               
angles                               1.9.13              
apturl                               0.5.2               
aqtp                                 0.0.10              
argcomplete                          1.8.1               
astunparse                           1.6.3               
atomicwrites                         1.1.5               
attrs                                19.3.0              
bcrypt                               3.1.7               
blinker                              1.4                 
breezy                               3.0.2               
Brlapi                               0.7.0               
cached-property                      1.5.2               
camera-calibration-parsers           1.12.0              
catkin                               0.8.10              
catkin-pkg                           0.5.2               
catkin-pkg-modules                   0.5.2               
certifi                              2019.11.28          
chardet                              3.0.4               
charset-normalizer                   2.1.0               
chex                                 0.1.5               
chrome-gnome-shell                   0.0.0               
Click                                7.0                 
cloudpickle                          3.0.0               
clu                                  0.0.7               
colcon-argcomplete                   0.3.3               
colcon-bash                          0.5.0               
colcon-cd                            0.1.1               
colcon-cmake                         0.2.28              
colcon-common-extensions             0.3.0               
colcon-core                          0.15.0              
colcon-defaults                      0.2.8               
colcon-devtools                      0.2.4               
colcon-installed-package-information 0.1.0               
colcon-library-path                  0.2.1               
colcon-metadata                      0.2.5               
colcon-notification                  0.2.15              
colcon-output                        0.2.13              
colcon-override-check                0.0.1               
colcon-package-information           0.3.3               
colcon-package-selection             0.2.10              
colcon-parallel-executor             0.3.0               
colcon-pkg-config                    0.1.0               
colcon-powershell                    0.4.0               
colcon-python-setup-py               0.2.8               
colcon-recursive-crawl               0.2.3               
colcon-ros                           0.4.1               
colcon-test-result                   0.3.8               
colcon-zsh                           0.5.0               
colorama                             0.4.3               
command-not-found                    0.3                 
commonmark                           0.9.1               
configobj                            5.0.6               
configparser                         5.0.0               
contextlib2                          21.6.0              
contourpy                            1.0.5               
controller-manager                   0.19.6              
controller-manager-msgs              0.19.6              
cov-core                             1.15.0              
coverage                             4.5.2               
cryptography                         2.8                 
cupshelpers                          1.0                 
cv-bridge                            1.16.2              
dacite                               1.6.0               
dbus-python                          1.2.16              
decorator                            5.1.1               
defer                                1.0.6               
defusedxml                           0.6.0               
Deprecated                           1.2.7               
diagnostic-updater                   1.11.0              
dill                                 0.3.5.1             
distlib                              0.3.6               
distro                               1.4.0               
distro-info                          0.23ubuntu1         
dlib                                 19.24.0             
dm-tree                              0.1.7               
docker                               4.1.0               
docker-compose                       1.25.0              
dockerpty                            0.4.1               
docopt                               0.6.2               
docutils                             0.16                
dulwich                              0.19.15             
duplicity                            0.8.12.0            
dynamic-reconfigure                  1.7.3               
einops                               0.5.0               
empy                                 3.3.2               
entrypoints                          0.3                 
etils                                0.8.0               
face-recognition                     1.3.0               
face-recognition-models              0.3.0               
Farama-Notifications                 0.0.4               
fasteners                            0.14.1              
fastimport                           0.9.8               
flatbuffers                          22.9.24             
flax                                 0.5.3               
flaxformer                           0.5.1               
fonttools                            4.37.4              
frozenlist                           1.3.1               
future                               0.18.2              
gast                                 0.3.3               
gazebo-plugins                       2.9.2               
gazebo-ros                           2.9.2               
gencpp                               0.7.0               
geneus                               3.0.0               
genlisp                              0.4.18              
genmsg                               0.6.0               
gennodejs                            2.0.2               
genpy                                0.6.15              
google-pasta                         0.2.0               
googleapis-common-protos             1.56.4              
gpg                                  1.13.1-unknown      
gymnasium                            0.29.1              
httplib2                             0.14.0              
huggingface-hub                      0.10.1              
idna                                 2.8                 
importlib-metadata                   5.0.0               
imutils                              0.5.4               
interactive-markers                  1.12.0              
jax                                  0.3.23              
jaxlib                               0.3.22              
joint-state-publisher                1.15.1              
joint-state-publisher-gui            1.15.1              
jsonschema                           3.2.0               
keras                                2.10.0              
Keras-Preprocessing                  1.1.2               
keyring                              18.0.1              
language-selector                    0.1                 
laser-geometry                       1.6.7               
launchpadlib                         1.10.13             
lazr.restfulclient                   0.14.2              
lazr.uri                             1.0.3               
libclang                             14.0.6              
line-bot-sdk                         2.3.0               
linecache2                           1.0.0               
lockfile                             0.12.2              
louis                                3.12.0              
lxml                                 4.9.1               
macaroonbakery                       1.3.1               
Mako                                 1.1.0               
MarkupSafe                           2.1.1               
message-filters                      1.16.0              
ml-collections                       0.1.1               
monotonic                            1.5                 
more-itertools                       4.2.0               
msgpack                              1.0.4               
multipledispatch                     1.0.0               
netifaces                            0.10.4              
nose                                 1.3.7               
nose2                                0.9.1               
notify2                              0.3                 
numpy                                1.23.4              
oauthlib                             3.1.0               
olefile                              0.46                
opencv-python                        4.4.0.44            
opt-einsum                           3.3.0               
optax                                0.1.3               
packaging                            20.3                
paramiko                             2.6.0               
pbr                                  5.4.5               
pexpect                              4.6.0               
Pillow                               9.3.0               
pip                                  20.0.2              
platformdirs                         3.1.1               
pluggy                               0.13.0              
promise                              2.3                 
protobuf                             3.6.1               
psutil                               5.5.1               
py                                   1.8.1               
pybind11                             2.4.3               
pycairo                              1.16.2              
pycryptodomex                        3.6.1               
pycups                               1.9.73              
PyGithub                             1.43.7              
Pygments                             2.3.1               
PyGObject                            3.36.0              
PyJWT                                1.7.1               
pymacaroons                          0.13.0              
PyNaCl                               1.3.0               
pyOpenSSL                            19.0.0              
pyparsing                            2.4.6               
PyQt5                                5.14.1              
pyRFC3339                            1.1                 
pyrr                                 0.10.3              
pyrsistent                           0.15.5              
pyserial                             3.5                 
pytest                               4.6.9               
pytest-cov                           2.8.1               
python-apt                           2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.7
python-dateutil                      2.7.3               
python-debian                        0.1.36ubuntu1       
python-gitlab                        2.0.1               
python-gnupg                         0.4.5               
python-qt-binding                    0.4.4               
pytz                                 2019.3              
pyxdg                                0.26                
PyYAML                               5.3.1               
pyzed                                3.7                 
qt-gui                               0.4.2               
qt-gui-cpp                           0.4.2               
reportlab                            3.5.34              
requests                             2.22.0              
requests-unixsocket                  0.2.0               
resource-retriever                   1.12.7              
roman                                2.0.0               
rosbag                               1.16.0              
rosboost-cfg                         1.15.8              
rosclean                             1.15.8              
roscreate                            1.15.8              
rosdep                               0.22.2              
rosdep-modules                       0.22.2              
rosdistro                            0.9.0               
rosdistro-modules                    0.9.0               
rosgraph                             1.16.0              
rosinstall                           0.7.8               
rosinstall-generator                 0.1.23              
roslaunch                            1.16.0              
roslib                               1.15.8              
roslz4                               1.16.0              
rosmake                              1.15.8              
rosmaster                            1.16.0              
rosmsg                               1.16.0              
rosnode                              1.16.0              
rosparam                             1.16.0              
rospkg                               1.5.0               
rospkg-modules                       1.5.0               
rospy                                1.16.0              
rosservice                           1.16.0              
rostest                              1.16.0              
rostopic                             1.16.0              
rosunit                              1.15.8              
roswtf                               1.16.0              
rqt-gui                              0.5.3               
rqt-gui-py                           0.5.3               
rviz                                 1.14.20             
scipy                                1.3.3               
screen-resolution-extra              0.0.0               
SecretStorage                        2.3.1               
sensor-msgs                          1.13.1              
setuptools                           59.5.0              
simplejson                           3.16.0              
sip                                  4.19.21             
six                                  1.16.0              
smclib                               1.8.6               
systemd-python                       234                 
tensorflow                           2.3.0               
tensorflow-cpu                       2.10.0              
tensorflow-datasets                  2.1.0               
tensorflow-estimator                 2.3.0               
tensorflow-hub                       0.12.0              
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem         0.27.0              
tensorflow-metadata                  1.10.0              
tensorflow-probability               0.18.0              
tensorflow-text                      2.10.0              
tensorstore                          0.1.27              
testresources                        2.0.0               
texttable                            1.6.2               
tf                                   1.13.2              
tf2-geometry-msgs                    0.7.6               
tf2-kdl                              0.7.6               
tf2-py                               0.7.6               
tf2-ros                              0.7.6               
toml                                 0.10.2              
toolz                                0.12.0              
topic-tools                          1.16.0              
torchaudio                           0.12.0+cu113        
torchvision                          0.7.0               
tqdm                                 4.64.1              
traceback2                           1.4.0               
typing-extensions                    4.7.1               
ubuntu-advantage-tools               27.9                
ubuntu-drivers-common                0.0.0               
ufw                                  0.36                
unattended-upgrades                  0.1                 
unittest2                            1.1.0               
urllib3                              1.25.8              
usb-creator                          0.3.7               
vcstool                              0.3.0               
vcstools                             0.1.42              
virtualenv                           20.21.0             
wadllib                              1.3.3               
wcwidth                              0.1.8               
websocket-client                     0.53.0              
wheel                                0.34.2              
wrapt                                1.11.2              
wstool                               0.1.18              
xacro                                1.14.16             
xkit                                 0.0.0               
zipp                                 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas what to check (or provide further information about):

- Have you sourced the ros dystro? (e.g. `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash` for noetic)
- Only because you are using ROS 1: Is `roscore` running? (if not run: `roscore`)
- Have you tried using a full `rqt_gui` (run: `rqt` or `rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui` ) to check if rqt_graph is available there?
- Have you installed `ros-%YOUR_ROS_DISTRO%-rqt-common-plugins` package as well (as [official installation guideline](https://wiki.ros.org/rqt/UserGuide/Install/Groovy) requests)? Because `rqt_graph` is part of this package (see [here](https://wiki.ros.org/rqt_common_plugins)).

Comment: 1. There's setup.bash under /opt/ros/noetic so I believed I did sourced the ros dystro
2. My roscore is up 24/7, checked and it's still running.
3.  When I run `rqt` or `rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui` , it'll just show a plain default rqt window with no plugins available.
4.  I'm not sure how to check this part (Is it suppose to show all plugins in pip list?) If I already have some plugin installed, will using `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-rqt ros-noetic-rqt-common-plugins`  again causes errors? (eh I didn't find a way to newline in comments)

Comment: Execute `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-rqt ros-noetic-rqt-common-plugins` should not cause any additional errors (as long as noetic is your ros dystro) and might be a good first try.
However `ros-noetic-rqt` (if it's already installed) might be removed and reinstalled which could cause problems with running processes, nodes, etc. (which might crash and therfore need a restart)

Comment: Welp, executing 'sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-rqt ros-noetic-rqt-common-plugins' did fix the problem. Must be not installing rqt properly a long time ago.